# Take the result of a MySQL query and put in another query

Tags: mysql, replace, addition, inner-query

7I have a table named "Critères"

Critères have two columns:

**"Prestation / Code hors projet" - "Heures"**

```
Salut                    20
Salut                    42
Salut                    35
Coco                     152
Coco                     -52
Lolilol                  89
```

I just need to have this result IN THE SAME TABLE:

**"Prestation / Code hors projet" - "Heures"**

```
Salut                    97
Coco                     100
Lolilol                  89
```

Is this clear ?

Please I really need help

I have this query for the moment: "SELECT Prestation / Code hors projet, SUM(Heures) FROM Critères GROUP BY `Prestation / Code hors projet`"

The problem is that I don't know what to do with the results =/

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by *need it in the same table*?

Comment: What do you mean: *I don't know what to do with the results*? Surely you do whatever you need to with them?

Comment: Should the sum of `Salut` not be 97?

Comment: You can do it in one query. Is it a need to seperate in two queries?

Comment: I've putted 77 due to a problem when I wrote it, fixed now (even if we just don't care...)

In fact I need to do the query on the table "Critères" (with all the 1st values) and after I truncate all the table to put the results in.
So I just have the results in. Is that clear now ? :)

If I can do it in only one query it's really cool ! Yes ! :p

Comment: So in the first part I have:

"Prestation / Code hors projet" - "Heures"

Salut                    20
Salut                    42
Salut                    35
Coco                     152
Coco                     -52
Lolilol                  89

And I want to have (and ONLY this):

"Prestation / Code hors projet" - "Heures"

Salut                    97
Coco                     100
Lolilol                  89

=)